# Forward /redirect friendly name email address to SFDC inbound email service

Tags: apex-email-service

Suppose I have a generic email say " test@gmail.com".
My requirement is whenever I get an email to this address then a record should be created in one of the custom object in salesforce.

I know that with Inbound Email services we can accomplish this but that requires email to be sent to an email as an ex :"mailfromcustomer@5xlhtrnl4z0t0lpgzosvszpejrhe9n4xgyron7sa6esckfq76.q-9bmueam.cs21.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com".  This incoded email gets generated with Email Service Configuration.

But I need to use some generic email like "test@gmail.com" to accomplish this requirement. So how do we map or re-direct the email which comes to "test@gmail.com" to salesforce generated email.

please let me know how to accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You would handle that kind of stuff on your mail server. If by "Generic Email" you mean a generic email address with the company's domain, just setup an email address on your mail server and have it redirect/forward stuff to that Salesforce email service address.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes , it is generic company email. fine I will go ahead with this approach. One more question, Is this the way we handle the requirement related to Inbound Email Services , because in real time customer  will not know the long/encoded salesforce generated email address for sending the email .

Comment: please reply to my above query

Comment: As a very basic example, your company sets up an email on the mail server (Exchange or whatever) with the address of "getaquote@companydomain.com". You want this email address to automatically go to your Salesforce inbound email service. So in Exchange, you redirect email sent to that address to *salesforce randomly generated email service email*. This way, when the customer sends an email to "getaquote@companydomain.com", it actually just goes right to your Inbound Email Service in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Google address, you can simply forward the message to the Salesforce address. Under settings in Google Mail, go to forwarding to configure it.

I've setup Google Apps with OnDemand email-to-case using forwarding.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the response. Actually it is not specific gmail account. It is comapny email and we would like to create one record in salesforce when we get an email on this email address.

Comment: Also when I tried to configure the forwarding setting for gmail account for testing purpose then it says that confirmation code has been sent on salesforce encoded email address. So how do we get the confirmation code from Encode auto-generated email address of salesforce.

Comment: please reply to above question

Comment: @arjunsingh You will have to have a working service to get it from Salesforce. It will be an inbound email that has the text with the code / link to verify you own that salesforce address.